# Cannot Confugure Sapling

Tags: add-on, sapling-addon

So, um. Ticked in curves sapling addon, then saved preferences. Now, after adding the tree, configuration menu is grey and even clicks can't activate it.

Thing tried:

1. Reactivating addon
2. Turning each addon

any solutions?

[[image: GrayMenu]]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, solution founded. All I had to do is tick "Global undo" in the Editing tab.

[image]